# Multiple Models

Tags: mvvm, knockout.js

I like knockoutjs, the sooner we get rid of coding directly toward the DOM the better. I'm having trouble understanding how I would do something which I'm going to explain in terms of a question/answer site. (This is probably a general MVC/MVVM question)

In my data model I have a question[id, description] and answer[id, question_id, text]. The browser requests a list of questions which is bound to a tbody, one column will display the question description, while the other should be bound to an answer textbox.

One obvious way of doing this is to have a QuestionAnswer[question_id, answer_id, question_descrition, answer_text] model. Ideally I'd like to keep them separate to minimize transformation when sending/receiving/storing, if there isn't some way of keeping them separate then I have the following question:

Where is the ideal place to create the QuestionAnswer model ? My bet is that by convention its created on the server.

If there is such an example somewhere please point me to it, otherwise I think it would make a good example.

Please help me wrap my head around this, Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, 
I'v gathered my thoughts on what my question is actually asking.
To do data binding on the client side you obviously need your data model there as well. I was conflicted on what I needed to send over and at what time.

To continue with the Question/Answer site idea: Sending down a list of answers each of which have a question in them is what should be done. That way you can bind to the answer list and simply bind the question description of each answer to the first table column.

If later I want to make a question editor I would potentially send a complete different data structure down and not reuse the Answer has a Question structure previously used.

I thought there might be a way of sending down a more complex data structure that references itself. Which apparently is possible in JSon with some extra libraries.

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is to create the combined model on the server, serialize it to json and then use the mapping plugin to add the serialized list to the view model.

I'm doing that [here](https://github.com/MikeEast/StringConvert.com/blob/master/StringConvert.WebClient/Views/index.cshtml#L57) only it isn't a combined model, but shouldn't make any difference. Especially since it seems like your relation is one-to-one.

If you need to create an "object" in your view model, you can use the mapping definition to do so, like I do [here](https://github.com/MikeEast/StringConvert.com/blob/master/StringConvert.WebClient/Views/index.cshtml#L47).

I use C# to build my [model](https://github.com/MikeEast/StringConvert.com/blob/master/StringConvert.WebClient/MainModule.cs#L16) on the server, but I guess you can use whatever you are comfortable with.

The cool thing with the mapping plugin is that it adds the data to the view model so that you can focus on behaviour.

Comment: Thanks, I'm also using MVC3. You example helped gather my thoughts.